# Closest pair of points O(nlogn) algorithm - problem with some data in c++ implementation

Tags: c++, points, closest

I have question about divide and conquer algorithm to find closest points. I checked C++ implementation on this page https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/closest-pair-of-points-onlogn-implementation/
But there is a problem with this code. It works fine in most cases, but for some data, this implementation returns other result, than brute-force method.
For example, lets take ten points (x, y):

```
(795 981)
(1905 4574)
(8891 665)
(6370 1396)
(93 8603)
(302 7099)
(326 5318)
(4493 3977)
(429 8687)
(9198 1558)
```

For this data, `O(n log n)` algorithm returns 944.298 instead of 346.341 given by brute force. Why is this happening?

This is exactly geeksforgeeks implementation with my example data:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <float.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

struct Point
{
    int x, y;
};

int compareX(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    Point *p1 = (Point *)a,  *p2 = (Point *)b;
    return (p1->x - p2->x);
}

int compareY(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    Point *p1 = (Point *)a,   *p2 = (Point *)b;
    return (p1->y - p2->y);
}


float dist(Point p1, Point p2)
{
    return sqrt( (p1.x - p2.x)*(p1.x - p2.x) +
                 (p1.y - p2.y)*(p1.y - p2.y)
    );
}

float bruteForce(Point P[], int n)
{
    float min = FLT_MAX;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        for (int j = i+1; j < n; ++j)
            if (dist(P[i], P[j]) < min)
                min = dist(P[i], P[j]);
    return min;
}

float min(float x, float y)
{
    return (x < y)? x : y;
}


float stripClosest(Point strip[], int size, float d)
{
    float min = d;  // Initialize the minimum distance as d 

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        for (int j = i+1; j < size && (strip[j].y - strip[i].y) < min; ++j)
            if (dist(strip[i],strip[j]) < min)
                min = dist(strip[i], strip[j]);

    return min;
}

float closestUtil(Point Px[], Point Py[], int n)
{
    // If there are 2 or 3 points, then use brute force 
    if (n <= 3)
        return bruteForce(Px, n);

    // Find the middle point 
    int mid = n/2;
    Point midPoint = Px[mid];


    Point Pyl[mid+1];   // y sorted points on left of vertical line 
    Point Pyr[n-mid-1];  // y sorted points on right of vertical line 
    int li = 0, ri = 0;  // indexes of left and right subarrays 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (Py[i].x <= midPoint.x)
            Pyl[li++] = Py[i];
        else
            Pyr[ri++] = Py[i];
    }

    float dl = closestUtil(Px, Pyl, mid);
    float dr = closestUtil(Px + mid, Pyr, n-mid);

    // Find the smaller of two distances 
    float d = min(dl, dr);

    Point strip[n];
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (abs(Py[i].x - midPoint.x) < d)
            strip[j] = Py[i], j++;

    return min(d, stripClosest(strip, j, d) );
}

float closest(Point P[], int n)
{
    Point Px[n];
    Point Py[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        Px[i] = P[i];
        Py[i] = P[i];
    }

    qsort(Px, n, sizeof(Point), compareX);
    qsort(Py, n, sizeof(Point), compareY);

    // Use recursive function closestUtil() to find the smallest distance 
    return closestUtil(Px, Py, n);
}

// Driver program to test above functions 
int main()
{
    Point P[] = {{795, 981}, {1905, 4574}, {8891, 665}, {6370, 1396}, {93, 8603}, {302, 7099},
                 {326, 5318}, {4493, 3977}, {429, 8687}, {9198, 1558}};
    int n = sizeof(P) / sizeof(P[0]);
    cout << closest(P, n) << std::endl;
    cout << bruteForce(P, n) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Has anyone idea what is wrong here? I have been trying fix it for few hours, but I don't really understand why this problem happens.

Comment: doesn't compile. Looks like you use VLA's (variable length arrays are a non-standard extension)

Comment: Which two points are the closest? I want to verify via math.

Comment: It requires C++11 or newer.

Comment: According to brute-force results, (93; 8603), (429; 8687) are closest - distance is 346.341

Comment: It does not require `-std=c++11`, it requires a compiler that provides a non-standard VLA extension to the C++ language (like gcc), to handle, e.g. `Point Pyl[mid+1];` and `Point Px[n];` (Be wary of code you find on the internet, especially from places like geeks... Much of the C++ is simply C rebranded as C++)

Comment: @MikolajMGT `Point Pyl[mid+1];` -- Not valid C++.  I know a lot of code looks like that on that website, but sorry to tell you, it's not valid C++ code.  Use `std::vector` instead.  What's worse, I've seen code on that site that uses `std::vector` in examples, *and* use non-standard VLA's in the same example, and sometimes in the same function.  That goes to show you that the author doesn't know what the purpose of `vector` actually is, or is just lazy.

Comment: Their implementation contains an of off-by-one error or two, and it will not handle input with more than one point with the same x coordinate. It is also written in extremely bad C++. [How to debug small programs](https://www.google.com/amp/s/ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/amp/)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Examples on geeks4geeks and similar sites should be viewed as pseudocode that incidentally can also be compiled with a real compiler and ran if the stars align the right way.

Comment: In the main loop of `closestUtil`, you should check that `li` and `ri` do not go out of bound

Comment: Just checking in again ... yes, you have a good counterexample. There are some comments on that link which are bug reports which might already have the fix. If those bugs were already fixed and the problem persists, then you should post your counterexample on that site so they can fix it again, but you'll have to do the debugging. Or they will. But their code, their bug, post it there. :)

Comment: I found this bug, in line 76 there is `if (Py[i].x <= midPoint.x)` instead of `if (Py[i].x < midPoint.x)` so arrays Px and Py are dividing unequal and `n` which is passing in recursive function is incorrect for some arrays. Thanks for support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Pyl` and `Pyr` have the sizes of `mid+1` and `n-mid-1` respectively, the following two lines

```
float dl = closestUtil(Px,     Pyl, mid  );
float dr = closestUtil(Px+mid, Pyr, n-mid);
```

should be rewritten as follows:

```
float dl = closestUtil(Px,       Pyl, mid+1  );
float dr = closestUtil(Px+mid+1, Pyr, n-mid-1);
```

In addition, as commented in the source code of [**this site**](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/closest-pair-of-points-onlogn-implementation/), in the above code it is assumed that all x coordinates are distinct. For instance, if all x coordinates are same, `li` is incremented from `0` to `n` and unexpected behavior occurs at `Pyl[li++] = Py[i];` when `li >= mid+1`.

---

BTW, VLA (Variable Vength Arrays) does not exist at all in the C++ specification. Since arrays `Px`, `Py`, `Pyl` and `Pyr` are created on stack with automatic storage duration, their sizes should be determined at compile-time. But some C++ compilers including GNU compiler support VLA as a compiler extension and allows declaring C-style arrays with a dynamic length. (How the memory is allocated for the VLA is implementation specific.) But C++ provides dynamic array functionality by `std::vector` which might make our code more readable, portable and robust.

Comment: Thanks for answer :)